# nested views in angularjs with each having separate controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a view

```
<section ng-controller="ParentController">
<!-- some contents -->
   <my-directive controller="ChildController"></my-directive>
</section>
```

script

```
    var app = angular.module('section', []);
    app.controller('ParentController', ['$scope', function($scope){
      //
    }]);
app.controller('ChildController', ['$scope', function($scope){
      //
    }]);

app.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    template : function(ele, args){
       return '<section ng-controller="+args.controller+" ></section>';
    },
    restrict  : 'E'
  }
});
```

Upon render i get, 'ChildController' is not a function, got undefined'

why is that so?

Comment: Did you mean angular.module('section', []); instead of angular.module('app', []); ?

Comment: You also want `<my-directive ng-controller="ChildController"></my-directive>` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ParentController', ['$scope', function($scope){
      //
    }]);
app.controller('ChildController', ['$scope', function($scope){
      //
    }]);
```